# How to unlock the Lightsaber in Solar Smash?

Tags: achievements, solar-smash

I've seen youtube videos where they use it, but I can't find how to get it. I think it's some kind of Easter Egg or Secret Achievement, but I can't find any information about it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to get the Order 66 Achievement, and you will unlock the Lightsaber as a reward. To get the order 66 achievement

1. Select Missile attack > then select multiple missiles
2. Set the values to 5 (Top row) & 66 (Bottom row)
3. To destroy the globe, aim at any area in the middle

[Source](https://www.mejoress.com/en/solar-smash-order-66-achievement-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to unlock the Lightsaber in Solar Smash you must use rockets. Simply open the tab containing them and select the basic nukes. Following that, **you must fire 66 rockets in a single shot** to unlock Lightsaber.

[Source](https://primagames.com/tips/how-to-unlock-the-lightsaber-in-solar-smash).